# "these days", can I use present simple and present continuous?

Tags: grammar

With "these days", can I use present simple and present continuous? If the answer is "yes", when can I use the present simple, and when can I use the present continuous?

Here are two sentences.

> These days, this newspaper is criticizing the government's new foreign policy.
>
> Sam plays basketball these days.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Both are grammatical and standard.

Comment: I don't know when I can use it in present simple and when in present continuous. Could you explain their usage to me, please?

Comment: You can use it in either situation—as you did in the question. It's essentially the same as how you would use the word [**now**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now). (Although *now* can be used in ways that *these days* cannot, you can substitute *now* for *these days* in the two sentences in the question.)